# Override directory's html code in tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, web-applications

I am working on windows 10, the website is running on Tomcat 9, and all directories and their content are in Web-Content folder of the dynamic web application.

The main problem is that when I add a link to the folder(localhost:8080/Project/files) they have the default html view file that that I can't locate and edit in my way.

I want to change the directory html code in order to add specific view to my portfolio. I`ve changed web.xml file to list directory content files, but I did not find any html file to edit. Is there a way to avoid writing hundreds of different html files with links to the folder content?

Comment: Can you give more details of where html are physical and what you changed, also is it on linux/windows?

Comment: I am working on windows 10. The website is running on Tomcat 9, and all directories and their content are in Web-Content folder of the dynamic web application. The main problem is that when I add a link to the folder(localhost:8080/Project/files) they have the default html view file that that I can`t locate and edit in my way